# Idiomatic search of value in a list of element-value pairs in Scala

Tags: scala

How to *idiomaticaly* search for an `value` in a list of `(element, value)` pairs in Scala?

Are there better (perhaps more succinct and/or efficient) ways than the following solution?

```
code.find(_._1 == 2).get._2
```

where `code` is of `List[(Int, String)]` type?

```
scala> val code: List[(Int, String)] = (0, "zero") :: (1, "one") :: (2, "two") :: Nil
code: List[(Int, String)] = List((0,zero), (1,one), (2,two))
scala> code.find(_._1 == 2).get._2
res0: String = two
```

Comment: You actually found *value*, not *element*

Comment: Doh, you're right! It's by mistake when I wrote element not value. I certainly meant value (without resorting to using a map). Sorry for confusion. I've just fixed the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about pattern matching?

```
 code.collectFirst{ case(2, x) => x }
```

This yields `Some(two)` which you can further `map`/`fold`.

Comment: Interesting. What's the name of the construct with case inside a function's body? Where is this described? I've only learnt about `match` and `case`'s for pattern matching not a single `case` in a function's body.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: this is how you can define *partial function*: http://blog.bruchez.name/2011/10/scala-partial-functions-without-phd.html

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
scala> code.toMap
res17: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(0 -> zero, 1 -> one, 2 -> two)

scala> res17(0)
res18: String = zero
```

Comment: Yes, but for one-time lookup it is highly inefficient. Someone may argue, but I tend to think writing inefficient scala code is not idiomatic ;-)